# How would I loop through products of the cart for an unregistered user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

```
# carts_controller.rb

class CartsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    if user_signed_in?
      @cart_products = current_user.cart.cart_products
    elsif session[:product_id]
      @cart_products = Product.where(id: session[:product_id])
    end
  end

  def add_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if user_signed_in?
      @cart_product = current_user.cart.cart_products.create(cart_id: current_user.cart, product_id: @product.id)
    else
      if session[:product_id]
        session[:product_id] << params[:id].to_i
      else
        session[:product_id] = [params[:id].to_i]
      end
    end
  end
  def destroy_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if user_signed_in?
      @cart_product = current_user.cart.cart_products.find_by(cart_id: current_user.cart, product_id: @product.id)
      @cart_product.destroy
    else
      session[:product_id].delete(params[:id])
    end
    redirect_to show_cart_path
  end
end
```

This is how I create cart product, which stores id of a product and id of a cart. Everything works unless the user is not signed in. **The unlogged user can add products (I saw it in sessions), but can't go to the cart.** And I don't understand why. I am attaching the picture of error (I added two products to the cart as anonymous user). I added `

```
<% cart_prod = cart_item.product %>
```

` in the view file, because otherwise the logged in user would not go to the cart (it would result in the error).

```
#carts/show.html.erb

<div class="flex flex-col justify-center text-center">
  <h1 class="font-bold text-4xl text-slate-100">Cart</h1>
</div>

<% if @cart_products.empty? %>
  <div class="m-8">
    <h1 class="text-white text-center"> Your cart is empty. Go fill it :) </h1>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 m-auto justify-center">
  <% @cart_products.each do |cart_item| %>
    <% cart_prod = cart_item.product %>
    <div class="max-w-sm bg-stone-900 rounded-lg dark:bg-stone-800 dark:bg-stone-800 ">
      <div class="bg-stone-600 rounded-tl-lg hover:rounded-tr-3xl">
        <div class="p-3 gif"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="px-5 pb-5">
        <a href="#">
          <h5 class="text-xl font-semibold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white"> <%= cart_prod.name %></h5>
          <h7 class="text-l font-semibold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white"> <%= cart_prod.description %></h7>
        </a>

        <div class="mt-3">
          <span class="text-3xl font-bold text-gray-900 dark:text-white"> <%= cart_prod.price %>$</span>

            <%= button_to "Remove from cart", destroy_cart_product_path(cart_prod), method: :delete,
              class: 'overline text-slate-50' %>
        </div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="p-3"></div>
  <% if @cart_products.present? %>
    <div class="text-center">
      <button class="text-white rounded-full focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none bg-slate-500 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center"> Order </button>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="p-3"></div>
```

[image]

```
_header.html file (a path to cart):

<%=  link_to 'Cart', show_cart_path,
                 class: "block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-white" %>
```

```
routes.rb:

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :categories, only: [:show, :index]
  resources :products, only: [:show, :index]
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions' }
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  root "shops#index"

  get 'cart/', to: 'carts#show', as: :show_cart
  post 'cart/:id', to: 'carts#add_product', as: :add_product_to_cart
  delete 'cart/:id', to: 'carts#destroy_product', as: :destroy_cart_product
end
```

```
cart model: 

class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :cart_products
  has_many :products, through: :cart_products
end
```

```
cart_product model:

class CartProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product
end
```

I am really stuck here. If you can help, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the naming is confusing you a bit `@cart_products.each do |cart_item|`

`cart_item` here is a `Product`, as you can see by looking at the output below the error.

Suggestion for solution/improvement...

```rb
@cart_products.each do |product|
  
end
```

Helpful hint, you can output a variable in a view to see what it contains with

```rb
<%= @cart_products.inspect %>
# or
<%= debug @card_products %>
```